# Is the difference between two UNIX TIMESTAMPs in two machines different?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that subtracts a unix timestamp from the timestamp representing the current time in javascript:

```
  var d1=new Date(1385890985000);//UNIX TIMESTAMP IN MILLISECONDS 
  var d2=new Date();

  var t1=d1.getTime();
  var t2=d2.getTime();

      if(t2-t1<60*60*1000)//1 hour
      {        
        alert(Math.floor((t2-t1)/60000)+" minute ago");                 
      } 
      else if(t2-t1<24*60*60*1000)//24 hours
      {        
        alert(Math.floor((t2-t1)/3600000)+" hour ago");                
      }
```

The script is fine in showing the difference of time in minutes or hours,such as 10 minutes ago or 7 hours ago etc.I have tested it in local timezone or with any other timezone and found it ok! But today in my college lab when I tried it in some of the machines it was again just fine with a disappointment in two machines with different timezones that show the difference differently: one shows 6 hours ago and the other shows 6 minutes ago although it shouldn't be so. Because UNIX timestamp is nothing but the numbers of seconds elapsed from the epoch year 1970 January 1. What is the wrong here? Any suggestions,tips or words of lesson is appreciated! All machines are lenovo desktop with Windows XP installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the time values you get from `Date#getTime` are milliseconds-since-the-Epoch and not affected by time zones.

The only explanation I can see (other than, with apologies, observational error or testing error) is that the machine where you get the surprising result is set to the wrong *time* (not just time zone). `new Date()` relies on the computer's current time being correct. In a lab with various machines set to various different timezones, it seems pretty easy to believe one of them might have had the wrong time set on it.

You might consider updating your test to give the UTC time the computer believes it is:

```
alert("This computer believes the current time, in UTC, is " + new Date().toUTCString());
```

I expect you'll find that the two machines (one where it said six hours and one where it said six minutes) don't think it's the same time.

Comment: ohhh thanx sir @T.J. Crowder Once I test it again in my lab, I will contact you.

Comment: I have observed that given a unix timestamp, if I compute x = new Date(timestamp),timezone-wise the time x.getHours()+":"+x.getMinutes() is different for different timezones with the same timestamp. But even if I change local time for each of the timezones, the time x.getHours()+":"+x.getMinutes() remains the same for each of the timezones! Am I right sir? I have tested it with x = new Date(1386254953000); @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @ParveezAhmed: `new Date(timestamp)` gives you a `Date` instance whose underlying UTC value is Jan 1st 1970 at midnight plus that many milliseconds. The `Date` object knows the timezone offset for local time (it gets it from the environment -- in this case, the browser), and uses it when you use `getHours` and similar. If you want to get the UTC values, use `getUTCHours` and similar. So for the same timestamp, `getHours` will vary by timezone; `getUTCHours` will not.